# Auto-increment the primary key without setting the identity

Tags: sql

I am using the following syntax to insert new records (I don't want to have duplicate keys):

```
insert into tbl(key) values select max(key)+1 from tbl
```

Someone says it will have concurrency problem.
Is that right?

```
SELECT -> LOCK table -> INSERT
```

or

```
LOCK table -> SELECT -> INSERT
```

Which one of the above is correct?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the native auto-increment feature?

Comment: In MySQL, at least, auto_increments and replication are fine together. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select will lock the table, and you are doing everything in a single statement, looks like you should be fine (other than maybe performance to calculate the max(key)).

Comment: Any reference link (e.g. msdn link) talking about this?

Answer (score 1):

If this happens inside a transaction you will be fine.

Comment: is that true. Does a begin transaction block other begin transactions? Couldn't they both calculate max(key) as the same?

Comment: If it's SERIALIZABLE then that's true, but I woudn't like to bet on it for any other isolation levels, especially CHAOS...

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing replication, your best bet is to use GUID's as a primary key and also "please" do not create clustered index on that column.